# When you add the article with the preposition "in"

Tags: difference

Why is it that there is no article here:

> Mein Freund hat um 15 Uhr einem Termin IN Hamburg

While we see one here:

> Wo Arbeitet dein Freund ?  IN DER Schweiz

Comment: What's the difference? You're (correctly) using "in" in both examples.

Comment: What I mean, is why it's in der schweiz and not just in Schweiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geographical entities that have a female or male gender are used with the article. The rest usually goes with "nach" and without the neuter "das", nowever, as CarstenSchultz mentioned in a comment, there are exception for which you do have to use the article. Whether or not that is specific to places in Germany, I don't know.

> die Schweiz, der Iran, die USA (plural), der Sudan, die Normandie, die Toskana
>
> (das) Deutschland, (das) Frankreich, (das) Hamburg, (das) Kreuzberg (district of Berlin), das Schweden, ...

Exceptions:

> ins Allgäu, ins Baskenland,...

Answer (score 0):

You should change the question to point out you are confused be the "DER" in "in der Schweiz"
This is a problem i never thought of.

You would say "In Holland", too.. but "In Schweiz" is wrong.
Locations that are not neutral (gender) require an article (as Emanuel said)

Further Examples are:
In den Niederlanden.
In den USA.
(while these are plurals, i don't know any other examples like Schweiz)

And be careful with islands, as island do not use "in" but "auf" - "Auf den Seychellen", "Auf Madagaskar" etc.

Comment: "in den Kantonen", vielleicht :)